# Understanding ethereum transaction

Tags: transactions, etherscan

I'm doin my combing through etherscan and am coming accross transactions called "remove sniper" and "set remove from fees" what does remove sniper mean on the blockchain

Answer (score 1):

Means nothing on the blockchain, but most is the name of the custom function being called inside a smart contract.

Take this account which shows said method inside their transactions for example: https://etherscan.io/address/0xa4bdb5c85358265ce421fa3c1b2d812ddf91ecef

If you check the transaction that "Remove the sniper", you can see that it interacted with [this contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0xa47861219642c8214d4f5f21cf9891f238ca07cb#code) containning a `RemoveSniper` function.